# .Net 7 ratelimiting change during runtime

Tags: c#, .net-7.0, rate-limiting

I'm testing the .Net 7 rate limiting, but have a situation where I want to change the rate limiting during runtime (for example when the limiting data is stored in a database).

I'm just testing with some default code I found on the internet.

```
builder.Services.AddRateLimiter(options =>
{
    options.GlobalLimiter = PartitionedRateLimiter.Create<HttpContext, string>(httpContext =>
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(httpContext.Request.Path);
       
        return RateLimitPartition.GetFixedWindowLimiter(
            partitionKey: "a",
            factory: partition => new FixedWindowRateLimiterOptions
            {
                AutoReplenishment = true,
                PermitLimit = 10,
                QueueLimit = 0,
                Window = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1)
            });
    });

    options.RejectionStatusCode = 429;
    options.OnRejected = async (context, token) =>
    {
        context.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = 429;
        if (context.Lease.TryGetMetadata(MetadataName.RetryAfter, out var retryAfter))
        {
            await context.HttpContext.Response.WriteAsync($"Too many requests. Please try again after {retryAfter.TotalSeconds} second(s)", cancellationToken: token);
        }
        else
        {
            await context.HttpContext.Response.WriteAsync("Too many requests. Please try again later", cancellationToken: token);
        }
    };
});

.
.
.
.
.

app.UseRateLimiter();
```

But I'm wondering how I can change the settings during runtime.
All examples I can find the values are set during startup, but never changed during runtime.

Anybody know how to do this?

tried different things like IOptions and change those in a controller, but I'm probably doing something wrong because none of them worked